# Make Helm Faster: add number for helm-buffer-lists and select command by first alphas

Tags: helm, helm-for-files, helm-selection

Does anyone know a package that can make helm faster when selecting **buffer** (helm-buffer-lists) or **command** (helm-M-x)?

For example:

1. add number for helm-buffer-lists (just like
   original **recentf-open-files** ) ,I can use an alternative number selection for buffers.
2. match commands for helm-M-x like this, **open-config-file** (as **ocf**), I think it can be an alternative selection when I type **ocf**. When select, place these selections at **top** (I think there are few additions than original matchs)

Answer (score 0):

I find how to add number for helm-buffers-list,just redefine this function with two points (in codes with comments) for adding line numbers.

```el
 (defun helm-highlight-buffers (buffers _source)
     "Transformer function to highlight BUFFERS list.
   Should be called after others transformers i.e (boring buffers)."

     (cl-loop for i in buffers
    ;;; **1. create number***************************************
         for number from 1 to (length buffers) 
         for (name size mode meta) = (if helm-buffer-details-flag
                         (helm-buffer--details i 'details)
                    (helm-buffer--details i))
           for truncbuf = (if (> (string-width name) helm-buffer-max-length)
                              (helm-substring-by-width
                               name helm-buffer-max-length
                               helm-buffers-end-truncated-string)
                            (concat name
                                    (make-string
                     (- (+ helm-buffer-max-length
                                                (length helm-buffers-end-truncated-string))
                                             (string-width name)) ? )))

           for len = (length mode)
           when (> len helm-buffer-max-len-mode)
           do (setq helm-buffer-max-len-mode len)
           for fmode = (concat (make-string
                                (- (max helm-buffer-max-len-mode len) len) ? )
                               mode)

           for formatted-size = (and size (format "%7s" size))
           collect (cons (if helm-buffer-details-flag
;;; **** 2. concat number at first ****************************
                             (concat (int-to-string number) " " truncbuf "\t" formatted-size
                                     "  " fmode "  " meta)
                           name)
            (get-buffer i))))
```

To select buffer like recentf-open-files, I define some keys for helm-map for selecting by alt+number.

```el
       ;;; add alt+number to select nth line
       (require 'cl)
       (cl-loop for n from 1 to 9
           for key = (format "M-%d" n)
           for fn = `(lambda ()
               (interactive)
               (helm-next-line ,(- n 1))
               (helm-maybe-exit-minibuffer)
               )
           do (progn
            (define-key helm-map (kbd key) fn)))
```